# Firebase datasnapshot.getValue() returns null

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, getvalue

In my app, I have used Firebase database and stored userID in a child and set the value of the child as username to get the username of the current user. Now I'm using addValueEventListener to get the username from the database. This is my Firebase structure.[image: Database Structure]

The code is given below.

```
checkUsername.child("check").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                currentUser = dataSnapshot.child(getUserID()).getValue(String.class);
                Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: currentUser = " + currentUser);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

While debugging, `String currentUser` returns null.

Screenshot of debugged answer.[image: Debugged Answer]

Comment: `addValueEventListener` used if one object but here there are two you should use `ChildEventListener` to get them

Comment: @AhmedAbd-Elmeged, Still it returns null...

Comment: what us value of `getUserId()`

Comment: getUserId() is a method that returns the String value of user id...

Comment: please check if you are getting correct value from `getUserId()`

Comment: I have checked. It's returning the correct userId of the user.

Comment: @AtifFarrukh Even without the userId it still returns null.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have added the valueEventListener at the `check` node, so getting the child again makes no sense (Because the User ID is the key of `check` node and not a separate child).

Instead try calling `dataSnapshot.getChildren();` directly to get the entire list of updated data and iterate through it to get whatever key value you need.

Something like this,

```
checkUsername.child("check").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {
       String current value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class); 
        Log.d("TAG", "onDataChange: " + current value);
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {}

    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {}

    @Override
    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String prevChildKey) {}

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
});
```

Another option in this particular use case is to add a ChildEventListener and get the value inside `onChildAdded()` method.

Comment: Check the updated answer and the screenshot. It still returns null.

Comment: I should have typed `ds` instead of `datasnapshot` there but I have checked, even it was `ds` it still returns null.

Comment: @Simon 
Directly call `ds.getValue(String.class);` and see if it returns null or not

Comment: Still returns null :(

Comment: Check the updated answer and see if it fixes the issue,

Comment: `String currentUser` doesn't show any value while debugging.

Comment: Ok, just check to see if the the user is authorized to access the db.

Comment: In your screenshot you loop over the `dataSnapshot.getChildren()` in `onChildAdded()`. That's not needed, since `onChildAdded()` already is invoked on each user node.

Comment: sorry for the delay... @the-dagger, how to check if the user is authorized or not.